# Re-use JPA entity hierarchy in two schemas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity hierarchy that I'd like to reuse in two different schemas.

```
   [Parent1]         [Parent2]
         \1            1/
          \            /
           \0..*  0..*/
         [ChildSuperclass]               -- @Inheritance(SINGLE_TABLE)
                 ^
                /_\
        _________|_________
       |                   |
[ChildSubclass1]    [ChildSubclass2]
```

I'd like to have four tables:

- `PARENT1`
- `CHILD1`
- `PARENT2`
- `CHILD2`

where CHILD1 and CHILD2 are mapped such that the class hierarchy and implementation can be shared.  Ideally, PARENT1/CHILD1 and PARENT2/CHILD2 would be in separate schemas, but I must use a single persistence unit.

I need a relationship to the superclass so it seems like @MappedSuperclass is not an option.  (However, Parent 1 does *not* need to reference Parent 2's children, nor vice versa.)

Is this possible?

Seems similar to this: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2419646
but I'm forced to use JPA annotations.  Hibernate-specific annotations are an option but XML is not.

I also can't see a way around multiple inheritance if I wanted to create a different subclass for each schema.  Separate class hierarchies with interfaces are my last resort.

**Update** Hopefully I can clarify with a more concrete example.

```
   [RedPerson]     [BluePerson]
         \1            1/
          \            /
           \0..*  0..*/
           [Automobile]               -- @Inheritance(SINGLE_TABLE)
                 ^
                /_\
        _________|_________
       |                   |
     [Sedan]    [PickupTruck]
```

For business reasons, Red people and Blue people need to have entirely separate tables and data.  If there was only a single type of Automobile, then I could just make it a mapped superclass and have PinkAuto and BlueAuto.  My question is how to do the same while preserving the hierarchy.  Does that help?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Why do you need `ChildSuperClass` here?

Comment: I want each parent to reference any of several possible child subtypes using a discriminator column.  (How do you represent a class hierarchy without a superclass?)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mis-read your diagram.

Comment: No problem, thanks for looking at it :-)

Comment: I've been staring at the diagram for a while, and i still don't get it, i'm afraid. The arrows you've drawn indicate inheritance between ChildSuperclass and the ChildSubclasses, but association between ChildSuperclass and the Parent classes. Is that correct? What is the meta-relationship between the inheritance and association relationships? Is it that instances of ChildSubclassN only have relationships with instances of ParentN?

Comment: Thanks very much Tom. I hope I clarified the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `@DiscriminatorColumn` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="childtype", discriminatorType=INTEGER)
public class ChildSuper{}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child1")
public class Child1{}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("child2")
public class Child2{}
```

Then, Parent1 can map to Child1, and Parent2 and map to Child2. But you still have the ChildSuper in the middle as a reference type and common code bin. And you can use it to query with.

Comment: JPA defaults to `@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DTYPE",discriminatorType=STRING)` and `@DiscriminatorValue` defaults to the SQL-ized entity name whenever `@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)` is used.  So adding them doesn't really change anything.  It also doesn't help map the hierarchy to two different tables/schemas.

Comment: Then I'm still misunderstanding what you're looking for. If you want the ChildSuper class, why does it have to be mapped as an entity? You can just make Parent1 care about Child1, and Parent2 care about Child2. Then have each child extend your ChildSuper, but keep it away from JPA. It seems like relationship 1 and relationship 2 are mutually exclusive anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at my problem. I hope I clarified the example.